# Multiple independent forms in a DetailView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have these simplified models. One Order can have multiple OrderItems. The OrderItems have a status ("A", "B" or "C").

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("A", "A"),
        ("B", "B"),
        ("C", "C"),
    )
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=False, default="A", max_length=1)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

Currently i use a DetailView, that shows one Order and loop through the OrderItems. Each OrderItem has a link to an UpdateView, to update the status:

**views.py**

```
class DetailOrder(DetailView):
    model = Order
```

**template**

```
{% for orderitem in object.items.all %}
    {{orderitem}}
    <a href={% url 'some-updateview' orderitem.pk %}>Update Status</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now to my question: how would I approach that for each orderitem an independent form is displayed to update the status directly in the DetailView instead of following a link to an UpdateView. Is that even possible?
Something like this, just to show the idea:

```
{% for orderitem in object.items.all %}
    {{orderitem}}
    {{form}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you find a way I'll interested also :)